# How can I access to the material of an imported 3DS file in Unity?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax, 3ds

I imported a big 3DS file to my Unity scene and I would like to make it transparent.

My object is as big that has been imported as a mesh with 5 different "sub meshes" inside and some of them have materials (already imported).

Can someone shed some light on how can I do it? I'm thinking that maybe I need to do a loop to go through all the sub meshes and check the material there... but honestly... if that is a solution... I do not know how to do it...I'm using C# but this are my first steps on Unity and C#.

Comment: It's a complex question. First of all, the import might not have been successful. Second, it is highly dependent on what models exactly you have, what's the complexity, do you have only diffuse textures or not, converted to left-hand coordinate system (Unity uses that) or not, etc. So if I was you I would start with 1, baby steps (small import), 2, convert to fbx and import that. According to transparency, read this article: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterAlbedoColor.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and sorry for not replying you before (busy days). I think I will start doing this step by step instead of starting with a super complex model that I didn't created... So you are right :) Thanks sir!

Comment: No worries. Good luck with your journey in 3D ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user Mark is right. I need to start with baby steps before understanding the complexity of it. Sometimes I'm running too fast!

Thanks a lot.